# C# Generic loop to return list w/ type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I noticed I had some duplicated code. How do I make this work in a more generic way?

The class structure is

```
class BaseObject
class MyBlock1 : BaseObject
class MyBlock2 : BaseObject
class MyBlock3 : BaseObject
```

The loop is:

```
private List<MyBlock1> GetVideosSection(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
    {
        List<MyBlock1> blocks = null;
        if (items != null)
        {
            blocks = new List<MyBlock1>();
            foreach (var reference in items)
            {
                var block = _repo.Get<MyBlock1>(reference.ContentLink);
                blocks.Add(block);
            }
        }
        return blocks;
    }
```

The loop is repeated for each implementation of `BaseObject`.

The `items` paremeter is a 'list' of references 'IDs' that are used to look up and return the appropriate object.

My attempt was along the lines of

```
private List<T> GetBlocks<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items) where T : BlockData, new ()
    {
        List<BaseObject> blocks = null;
        if (items != null)
        {
            T typeDeclaredInMethod = T from GetBlocks<T>;
            blocks = new List<  typeDeclaredInMethod >();
            foreach (var reference in items)
            {
                var block = _repo.Get< typeDeclaredInMethod >(reference.ContentLink);
                blocks.Add(block);
            }
        }
        return blocks;
    }
```

I realize the above code is not valid but is there to illustrate my intent.
I am new to C# and not sure how generic methods work so not sure if this is even possible.
How can I write this loop to work for all implementations of `BaseObject`?

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
List<MyBlock1> block1List = GetBlocks<MyBlock1>( items );
List<MyBlock2> block2List = GetBlocks<MyBlock2>( items );
List<MyBlock3> block3List = GetBlocks<MyBlock3>( items );
```

or

```
List<BaseObject> block1List = GetBlocks<MyBlock1>( items );
```

Comment: What about your attempt didn't work, specifically?

Comment: `return items?.Select(item => _repo.Get<T>(item.ContentLink)).ToList();`

Comment: Please post the code from your failed attempt.

Comment: @Servy

I have updated the failed attempt, not sure if it is possible

Comment: @JohnWu ^^^^^^^

Comment: seems as if you want a pattern vs making generics work, have you heard of factory pattern? http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern is a link to that pattern and how to use it. Instead of 3 separate lists, you could create a single list that can handle each derived type (see override void CreatePages)

Comment: You have a design problem in your method; it is a bad practice to accept a null sequence and to return a null sequence in turn.  Your code should *crash* when given a null sequence and always return a non-null sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is close but you don't need to get `T`, you already have it:

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
    {
        List<T> blocks = null;
        if (items != null)
        {
            blocks = new List<T>();
            foreach (var reference in items)
            {
                var block = _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink);
                blocks.Add(block);
            }
        }
        return blocks;
    }
```

I would write it as follows:

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items) => items?.Select(reference => _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink)).ToList();
```

Comment: so you're saying, if I declare T in the signature and reference T within the method body - T will evaluate as the inferred type?

Comment: @AlexPlouff: What exactly do you mean by "inferred type"?  There is no type inference going on anywhere in NetMage's first solution. (The second solution infers the type argument in the calls to Select and ToList.)

Comment: So if I have List<MyBlock1> = GetBlocks<MyBlock1>( param )
the T in _repo.Get< T >( ) will evaluate to MyBlock1 ?

Comment: @AlexPlouff: Suppose you have `int d(int x) { return x + x; }` If we have `d(1)` will the `x`s in `x + x` evaluate to `1`?  Of course they will.  The whole *point* of function abstraction is *the parameters are replaced at runtime with the values of the supplied arguments*.  Generics are not different.  **The generic type parameter T is replaced at runtime with the value of the generic type argument supplied**, just as normal formal parameters are replaced with the values of their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by saying how to perform the generalization.  We start with:

```
private List<MyBlock1> GetVideosSection(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
{
    List<MyBlock1> blocks = null;
    if (items != null)
    {
        blocks = new List<MyBlock1>();
        foreach (var reference in items)
        {
            var block = _repo.Get<MyBlock1>(reference.ContentLink);
            blocks.Add(block);
        }
    }
    return blocks;
}
```

We wish to parameterize this to eliminate the `MyBlock1`, so we simply declare a new *type parameter* T and search-and-replace `MyBlock1`:

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
{
    List<T> blocks = null;
    if (items != null)
    {
        blocks = new List<T>();
        foreach (var reference in items)
        {
            var block = _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink);
            blocks.Add(block);
        }
    }
    return blocks;
}
```

Are we done?  We're done with the original task, but **always take the opportunity to ask if you could do better**. Can this method be improved?  Sure.  We can notice for example that the contract of "accepts and returns null" is terrible. It is error prone and wrong. Empty sequences are *cheap*. Don't treat a null as an empty sequence.  Neither accept them nor return them.

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    List<T> blocks = new List<T>();
    foreach (var reference in items)
    {
        var block = _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink);
        blocks.Add(block);
    }
    return blocks;
}
```

Much better. Are we done?  No. We see now that our loop is simply a selection:

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    var query = from reference in items 
                select _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Or if you prefer

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    return items.Select(reference => _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink)
                .ToList();
}
```

Can we do better still? In C# 7 we can put a throw in the body of a conditional expression and make an expression-bodied method:

```
private List<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items) => 
  items == null ? 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("items") :
    items.Select(reference => _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink)
         .ToList();
```

And now we might ask ourselves, do we really need the ToList?  What if the caller wants to further filter the result, say, with a `Where`?  It's premature to make this a list:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items) => 
  items == null ? 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("items") :
    items.Select(reference => _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink));
```

or if you prefer:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetVideosSection<T>(IEnumerable<ContentAreaItem> items) => 
  items == null ? 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("items") :
    from reference in items select _repo.Get<T>(reference.ContentLink);
```

If the caller wants a list then they can say `GetVideosSection<Whatever>(items).ToList()` and hey, they've got a list.

Look at how concise and understandable that is compared to your original code. The original code says "the most important thing about this method is the list that I am filling in with this loop".  This version of the code emphasizes the meaning: *I am fetching the content from the repo associated with each item*.

Comment: holy shit! a little above and beyond. Thanks for the details :)